# Understanding Factory provider parameter in angular4

Tags: angular, angular-factory

I am confused with the parameter for the factory provider in angular4.
suppose if i am using a factory provider like this

**scenerio 1**

```
{ 
provide: PREFERRED_BOOKS, 
useFactory: () => { return 'foo@yahoo.com'; }, deps: [Book, BookService] 
}
```

now, the useFactory provider is a function, and we are returning a string

**scenario 2**

if i do the same thing like this

```
 { 
provide: PREFERRED_BOOKS,
 useFactory: preferredBooksFactory(), deps: [Book, BookService] 
}

function preferredBooksFactory() {
  return 'foo@yahoo.com';
};
```

I am getting compilation error, where i shouldnt be getting compilation error  because all i did was passed a function to the provider

**scenario 3**

when i change my function like this, then it works fine

```
export function preferredBooksFactory() {
  return (): string => {
    return 'foo@yahoo.com';
  };
};
```

can anyone please explain me what is happening and what am i missing

Comment: in scenario 2, you want `useFactory: preferredBooksFactory,`, not `useFactory: preferredBooksFactory(),`, because `useFactory` takes a function, not a function call that results in a string.

Comment: could you also explain me how does the scenario 3 works, thanks

Comment: ok, i got that, thank you very much !!!

Comment: If you understand scenario 2 now, then 3 becomes clearer. Scenario 3 is referencing the return value of a function which returns `a function that returns a string`, as opposed to 2 which (when fixed) is referencing `a function that returns a string`.